# Regex to remove specific string if exist

Tags: c#, regex, string

I wanna remove the `-L` from the end of my string **if exists**

So

```
ABCD   => ABCD
ABCD-L => ABCD
```

at the moment I'm using something like the line below which uses the `if/else` type of arrangement in my Regex, however, I have a feeling that it should be way more easier than this.

```
var match = Regex.Match("...", @"(?(\S+-L$)\S+(?=-L)|\S+)");
```

Comment: and `string.Replace and string.Contains` method won't work for you..? [String.Replace(string, string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: this is part of fairly big Regex which if I want to break it down to a c# code it'll translate to fair amount of lines. That's all.

Comment: once again why use regex if you don't understand it .. use string.Replace it's easier to understand and incorporate string.Contains method

Comment: Let's say, I appreciate your input and I am not against using it. I just simply can't stop learning something because there are other way's of doing it. Thanks again for the suggestion.

Comment: I am not saying stop learning but I can't understand how someone would want to do something in RegEx that's easier to do in C# .net I am just saying.. perhaps you may want to read up on Replace function in RegEx since it's apparent that you failed to do a simple google search on that subject T

Comment: @DJKRAZE How are you planning to detect the end of a string/word using `string.Replace`?

Comment: I'd say String.EndsWith()

Comment: @Mehrad True for the end of a string, but not for the end of words in the string.

Comment: Well, since I failed to do a simple Google search I don't think I am allowed to say, Regex has it's own advantages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about just doing:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("-L$");
string result = rgx.Replace("ABCD-L", "");
```

So basically: if the string ends with `-L`, replace that part with an empty string.

If you want to not only invoke the replacement at the end of the string, but also at the end of a word, you can add an additional switch to detect word boundaries (`\b`) in addition to the end of the string:

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("-L(\b|$)");
string result = rgx.Replace("ABCD-L ABCD ABCD-L", "");
```

Note that detecting word boundaries can be a little ambiguous. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#WordCharacter) for a list of characters that are considered to be word characters in C#.

Comment: Does`Replace` only work when `rgx.Sucess` is `true`?

Comment: @Mehrad What's `rgx.Sucess`? Can't find that property anywhere. Anyway, if nothing is matched, nothing is replaced.

Comment: That's all I meant. Very useful. Thanks. Meanwhile, if you go like `var matchL = Regex.Match(...);` you'll get a property for `matchL` called `Sucess` of a type `bool` which indicates if there was a result for the Regex match.

Answer (score 2):

You also can use String.Replace() method to find a specific string inside a string and replace it with another string in this case with an empty string.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use `Regex.Replace` function,

```
Regex.Replace(string, @"(\S+?)-L(?=\s|$)", "$1")
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/gP1eN6/2)

**Explanation:**

```
(                        group and capture to \1:
  \S+?                     non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                           and " ") (1 or more times)
)                        end of \1
-L                       '-L'
(?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
  \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
 |                        OR
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                           the string
)                        end of look-ahead
```

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can use Regex for this, but why when using normal string functions is clearer?

Compare this:

```
text = text.EndsWith("-L")
    ? text.Substring(0, text.Length - "-L".Length)
    : text;
```

to this:

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"(\S+?)-L(?=\s|$)", "$1");
```

Or better yet, define an extension method like this:

```
public static string RemoveIfEndsWith(this string text, string suffix)
{
    return text.EndsWith(suffix)
        ? text.Substring(0, text.Length - suffix.Length)
        : text;
}
```

Then your code can look like this:

```
text = text.RemoveIfEndsWith("-L");
```

Of course you can always define the extension method using the Regex. At least then your calling code looks a lot cleaner and is far more readable and maintainable.

Comment: Your comparison is wrong. You should compare your solution to `new Regex("-L$").Replace(text, "");`

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen - That code is certainly better than the Regex that I used, but it is still less than obvious as to what it does.